# Amplitude corresponding to a particular frequency after performing FFT

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

An input signal is coming at particular frequency. I am performing FFT on that and then want to find the amplitude corresponding to that particular frequency. I am not sure if I am going in correct direction? Here are the 2 functions I came up with:

```
def fft_v2(y, freq, fs=30000):
    Ts = 1.0/fs; # sampling interval
    t = np.arange(0,1,Ts) # time vector

    n = len(y) # length of the signal
    k = np.arange(n)
    T = n/fs
    frequency = k/T # two sides frequency range
    frequency = frequency[range(n/2)] # one side frequency range

    Y = np.fft.fft(y)/n # fft computing and normalization
    Y = Y[range(n/2)]

    amplitude = []

    for fq,amp in zip(frequency, Y):
        if fq == freq:
            amplitude.append(max(abs(Y)))

    print max(amplitude)


def fft(y, freq, fs=30000):
    n  = len(y)      # Get the signal length
    dt = 1/float(fs) # Get time resolution

    fft_output = np.fft.rfft(y)     # Perform real fft
    rfreqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, dt) # Calculatel frequency bins
    fft_mag = np.abs(fft_output)    # Take only magnitude of spectrum

    # Normalize the amplitude by number of bins and multiply by 2
    # because we removed second half of spectrum above the Nyqist 
    # frequency and energy must be preserved   
    fft_mag = fft_mag * 2 / n           

    print np.array(fft_mag), np.array(rfreqs)
```

In the second function, how to find amplitude corresponding to particular frequency??

Comment: If the particular frequency of interest is at index `i` in the array `rfreqs`, then the corresponding amplitude would be at the same index `i` in the array `fft_mag`.

Comment: there length is not equal.
length of fft_mag = 2 * length of rfreqs + 2

Comment: Running your `fft` function I get `len(fft_mag) == len(fft_output) == floor(n/2)+1`, and `len(rfreqs) == floor(n/2)+1`.

Comment: I resolved the issue by using a new fft function all together

Comment: Perhaps you could post your solution if it can help future readers